# Facing issue with CI CD pipeline using Google Compute Engine & Github

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am getting this error:

ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

I am trying to setup a trigger such that whenever there is a "PUSH" action to my repository, it should trigger the cloud `pull.sh` file What am I missing? I changed my default-ssh setting from firewall to allow 22 port requests for TCP & UDP both. Still cannot figure what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the command again?

If you are experiencing the same error, try:

Create a SSH key Open a terminal window.

Create a new directory named workingdir and navigate into it:

```
mkdir workingdir
```

```
cd workingdir
```

Create a new GitHub SSH key, where github-email is your GitHub email address:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -f id_github -C github-email
```

Here is the [reference](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build#create_a_ssh_key).

After creating a new SSH keys, you can use this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build#store_the_private_ssh_key_in) for storing the private SSH key in the Secret Manager.